show the recently played songs in flutter
I fetched data of songs from firebase realtime database, now I have to show the recently played songs in my app in flutter, assume all music playing functionality is proper.
am confused in what to try, somewhere it's showing- use so and so package but all is very confusing.

Please edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
